# How to get info from a window and the modify it using AutoIT?

Tags: autoit

I am trying to automate the process of turning display layers on and off in a modeling program using AutoIt. I am currently using code that simply simulates a mouse-click at a particular pixel position and as that of course needs to be set up differently depending on the screen being used at the time, I would like to replace the mouse-click simulation with getting the information from the window, looking for a certain text, then checking or unchecking the "Map" and "Legend" check boxes.

My problem is that I don't know how to do that. If someone has a good way to include or point to screen shots let me know but until then I will try to describe everything the best that I can.

The window:
The window I am referring to is titled "Map Layers". The area that I am specifically interested is looks like a large list box (it takes up the vast majority of the window space) and it has 4 columns: Layer Name, Map, Legend, and Sample. Name has the name of the layer, Map has a check box to control which layers are displayed, Legend has a check box that controls which layers appear in the legend window, and Sample for some layers has the symbol that will appear in the legend. for my purpose the Sample column is irrelevant.

AutoIt v3 Window Info:
When I use the finder tool I can't get it to highlight the "list box" area, only the surrounding boarder that it and some buttons are in. The window info says that this surrounding boarder area (which seems similar to a panel) has a class of Button.

So my fundamental question is what code to use to drill into that "Button", find out what the list view looking thing is, and get the info from it, then interact with the map and legend check boxes without referring to pixel location (or at least grammatically get the pixel position).

If I have left out any important information or was unclear anywhere please let me know.

Edit: Forgot to mention and don't know if it helps but the info given using the finder tool for the column headers is Control: Class: SysHeader32

Answer (score 1):

Try [RanorexSpy](http://www.ranorex.com/gui-testing-guide/spy.html) and see if it can give you more details.